# SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener being blocked

Tags: android, soundpool

I'm trying to load a sound so that it is available to be played later in my activity, and I want to ensure that it has finished loading before I finish onCreate (sometimes it will be played pretty much immediately by a Handler method.

Frequently I get the error "sample 1 not READY" if the sound is to be played straight away.

So I went searching for an answer, and pretty much everyone is saying to use SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener, but I tried that and it doesn't seem to do anything useful. It's like it waits for my onCreate method and everything else to finish before it is called, so if I try and get my onCreate to wait for the onLoadComplete call then nothing happens.

Below is a simple test program to demonstrate (note that in the real program the call to play_sound() won't be in onCreate, it will be called from elsewhere, but possibly very quickly).

Below the program is the log file output from LogCat.

If I comment out all the stuff related to OnLoadCompleteListener and the while(sound_loaded) loop, and instead just put in a 'SystemClock.sleep(100)' it pretty much works perfectly, but this feels like it's cheating.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private static HashMap<Integer, Integer> soundMap;
private SoundPool sounds;
private boolean sound_loaded = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "onCreate started");

    sounds = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    soundMap = new HashMap();
    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Loading sound");

    sounds.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener() {
        public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool sp, int sid, int status) {
            Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Sound is now loaded");
            sound_loaded = true;
    }});

    soundMap.put(1, sounds.load(this, R.raw.ping_da_ding_ding_ding, 1));
    //SystemClock.sleep(100);
    play_sound();

    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "onCreate Finished");
}

public void play_sound() {
    int loop_counter = 0;   
    while (sound_loaded == false) { 
        if (loop_counter++ > 3) {
            Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Looped too many times, breaking out!");
            break;
        }
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "sleeping waiting for sound");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();}
    }   

    int sound_stream = sounds.play(soundMap.get(1), 0.5f, 0.5f, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

The log output

```
 12-16 17:55:13.025: D/MainActivity(22322): onCreate started
 12-16 17:55:13.030: D/MainActivity(22322): Loading sound
 12-16 17:55:13.035: D/MainActivity(22322): sleeping waiting for sound
 12-16 17:55:13.045: V/MediaPlayer(22322): decode(55, 753, 5391)
 12-16 17:55:14.035: D/MainActivity(22322): sleeping waiting for sound
 12-16 17:55:15.035: D/MainActivity(22322): sleeping waiting for sound
 12-16 17:55:16.035: D/MainActivity(22322): sleeping waiting for sound
 12-16 17:55:17.035: D/MainActivity(22322): Looped too many times, breaking out!
 12-16 17:55:17.045: I/Reverb(22322):  getpid() 22322,  IPCThreadState::self()->getCallingPid() 22322
 12-16 17:55:17.050: D/MainActivity(22322): onCreate Finished
 12-16 17:55:17.120: D/(22322): Sound is now loaded
```

I'm running this on an Asus Nexus 7 (android 4.2.1) and also a Samsung Galaxy S3 (android 4.0.4)

Thanks
Kevin

Comment: try to play sound in new thread.

Answer (score 1):

This line `Thread.sleep(1000);` in the function of `play_sound()`  is actually blocking your main thread **(UI Thread)**.

Comment: Maybe my design is going off in the wrong direction, but my thinking was that it is necessary to block the main thread in order to give the SoundPool a chance to finish loading the sound and catch up. Or have I completely missed the point of the Listener?

Comment: you better see this before using sound pool :-http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidMedia/article.html

Comment: You should NOT block your UI thread to do something that can be done in the background.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do this:

```
sounds.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener() {
    public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool sp, int sid, int status) {
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Sound is now loaded");
        sound_loaded = true;
        soundMap.put(1, sounds.load(this, R.raw.ping_da_ding_ding_ding, 1));
        play_sound();
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "onCreate Finished");
    }
});
```

Currently, you are setting the OnLoadCompleteListener ... and going immediately to call play_sound(). You don't want to call play_sound() until the OnLoadComplete() fires.

Comment: I think I blew that one. I DON'T think you want the sounds.load() inside the onLoadComplete, but you DO want the play_sound() in it.